# Installing VTK on MAC (CMake Policy CMP0022 is not set)

Tags: macos, cmake, vtk

Since couple of days I've been struggling with installing VTK on the latest Mavericks.
I've tried different types of installation, but I got an error:

```
CMake Warning (dev) in Common/Core/CMakeLists.txt:
   Policy CMP0022 is not set: INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES defines the link
   interface.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0022" for policy details.  Use the
   cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Target "vtkCommonCore" has an INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES property which
  differs from its LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES properties.

  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES:

 vtksys

  LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES:



 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

I was trying to set policy in CMakeLists.txt file

```
 if(POLICY CMP0020)
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0020 NEW)
 endif()
```

but I got an error

```
 CMake Error in Common/Core/CMakeLists.txt:
  Target "vtkCommonCore" has policy CMP0022 enabled, but also has old-style
LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES properties populated, but it was exported without
  the EXPORT_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES to export the old-style properties



 CMake Error in IO/NetCDF/CMakeLists.txt:
  Target "vtkIONetCDF" has policy CMP0022 enabled, but also has old-style
  LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES properties populated, but it was exported without
  the EXPORT_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES to export the old-style properties
```

Please, help me. VTK drives me crazy

Answer (score 0):

1) It's a warning, not an error.

2) When you set the policy, you set the wrong policy.

Comment: It might be only a warning,but I was trying to compile examples and it was impossible,because the system couldn't see installed vtk.

Comment: In that case you didn't describe the problem you hit.